# Drawing a picture with equations

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions, calculator

I have a school project where I have to create an image on my calculator by forming equations. I want to create the Apple logo and have been trying a lot but I can't come up with any equations. My calculator is the TI-84 Plus and my graph needs to be in radian mode and it can't be polar or anything (just the standard function mode). It would be awesome if you could help me out.

Comment: See [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+apple+logo)

Comment: @martin, good one, it is so complex, must have fallen of a UFO or something....:) - Thx for sharing.

Comment: Not sure if your calculator can do this, but it may give you an idea:https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/spin-off-of-apple-logo23/5544099506028544

Comment: @martin I'm not sure what that link is. I need to graph the Apple logo with multiple equations on my calculator.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a homework, and the solution would take time to develop, I post this text as a **Hint**:

If you want to create a picture composed of several equations, the general idea is to divide the picture to parts where each part could be represented with a curve in a given range. Better yet to begin with symmetrical parts and then figure out the curve(s) that would represent each part. The following is an example and not an exact answer to your question, you may use it as a starting point. I don't have your calculator model handy, so I can't tell what ti can and can't do, but again.
This example was prepared quickly using a very nice calculator called Dismos, you can play with it too until you get your final answer. [Deimos-Calculator Logo Example](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/psvyh3wijz).